# parse push notifications - how to track opens from REST or JS API

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, push-notification, cordova-plugins

How do you track push opens from Javascript. I'm getting my notifications successfully through [$cordovaPush](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/), but the Parse docs only explain how to track opens from IOS. Has anyone figured out how to do this from JS?

https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving-tracking/iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript SDK does not currently support receiving pushes. To learn more about handling received notifications in iOS or Android, use the platform toggle at the top. (as of May 2015)